# How to close dialog by Selenium?

Tags: java, wordpress, selenium, dialog

I want close browser file window pop-up (when I upload picture to Wordpress).

[image]

I tried

```
driver.close();
driver.findElement(By.id("set-post-thumbnail")).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

but it doesn't work. How to close dialog by Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

OS Specific dialogs like File Browser can not be controlled by Selenium.
It can handle only WebElements or JavaScript/Browser Alerts.

In this specific case, I think it is upload file browser.
Workaround may be to pass the absolute path if some text input field is provided along with "Browse" button.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I try setKey(); to button and around path. but I couldn't upload file...

which path can I upload file on wordpress upload window?